# как спрятать вложенный список <ul> под родительский список (z-index)

Tags: css, z-index

Есть примерно така html структура и css стили.

```css
ul{
padding: 0;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 1000; /* * */
  background-color: #ccffcc;
}

header .menu-container {
  display: flex;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

header ul.menu-container li {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .3s;
  z-index 1100; /* * */
}

header ul.menu-container li:hover {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}

header .menu-container li ul.dropdownMenu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-top: none;
  top: 30px; /* нормальная высота = 50px, сейчас указано 30px чтобы было видно слои */
  left: 0px;
  color: black;
  background: #ff8080;
  z-index: 500;  /* * */
}

header .menu-container li ul.dropdownMenu li {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="menu-container">
    <li>Пункт 1
      <ul class="dropdownMenu">
        <li>Категория 1</li>
        <li>Категория 2</li>
        <li>Категория 3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Пункт 2</li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

**Вопрос:** как сделать так, чтобы подменю спряталось под header> Это нужно для того, чтобы сделать анимацию плавного выпадающего меню.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `header ul.menu-container li` нужно оставить только `position: relative;`

А у `header .menu-container li ul.dropdownMenu` нужно поставить отрицательный `z-index: -1;`

А во всех остальных местах нужно убрать position и z-index

```css
ul{
padding: 0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ccffcc;
}

header .menu-container {
  display: flex;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

header ul.menu-container li {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .3s;
}

header ul.menu-container li:hover {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}

header .menu-container li ul.dropdownMenu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-top: none;
  top: 30px; /* нормальная высота = 50px, сейчас указано 30px чтобы было видно слои */
  left: 0px;
  color: black;
  background: #ff8080;
  z-index: -1;  /* * */
}

header .menu-container li ul.dropdownMenu li {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="menu-container">
    <li>Пункт 1
      <ul class="dropdownMenu">
        <li>Категория 1</li>
        <li>Категория 2</li>
        <li>Категория 3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Пункт 2</li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: отлично, это решает проблему. Но вот еще вопрос: Если z-index отрицательный (-1), то это меню тогда будет находиться ПОД контентом страницы? То есть нажать на него нельзя будет. 
Как это исправить? <main> сделать z-index: -2 ? Это будет правильно?

Comment: @YuriiSpace, а вы уже пробовали? =) Просто, я не знаю)

Comment: Да, суть в том, что z-index должен быть именно отрицательный. Если установить для родительских элементов z-index (например) 1000, а для самого выпадающего меню 900, то так это не работает.
Проблема в том, что если у этого выпадающего меню z-index отрицательный то контент страницы накрывает меню и тогда по нему невозможно кликнуть